# PFQuery Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

```
func findEmployee(completion: (array: [AnyObject], error: String?) -> Void) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Employee")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in
        var employeeArray = [PFEmployee]()
        if let error = error {
            let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as? String
            completion(array: employeeArray, error: errorString)
        } else {
            for employee in results! {
                let currentEmployee: PFEmployee = employee as! PFEmployee
                employeeArray.append(currentEmployee)
            }
            completion(array: employeeArray, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code that is used to query data from the "Employee" class in Parse. For some reason, nothing is getting queried. What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you describe your investigation so far?  SO frowns on pasting code and asking why it doesn't work.  There's even a close category stating exactly that.

Comment: Unrelated to the weakness in the question, I think the whole completion block can be replaced with one line: `completion(array: array, error: error)`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the array of employees doesn't exist in memory and your UI isn't trying to load the data before the background task has completed? You may need to put your completion block inside of this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    completion(.....)
}
```

That's how I do it in my Parse app and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried implementing this, but it still does not work.

Comment: Have you tried adding in print statements/debugging at each section in your query block to see where it's executing or not?

Comment: Yes. When I call the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock method, I inserted the print statement with the array returned back from parse with all of the data. The array that is returned was empty.

Comment: I even checked the class name, just to be sure, and it is fine

Comment: The completion block runs on the main thread.  @JustinStanley, you can remove these from your code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace [AnyObject] with [PFObject]? Instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer again! This still did not work, because when I call this method, I cast the array to an array of type PFObject.

Comment: I don't see PFObject, just PFEmployee. Maybe it is failing at that point as it can't properly cast from PFObject to your custom PFEmployee object?